# Must supply a value for form control with name: 'invoice_name'?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, setvalue, formgroups

I'm facing to a problem concerning my form. When I click on update button it should retrieve informations through a form, but I have this following issue :

> Must supply a value for form control with name: 'invoice_name' ?

I checked some help concerning SetValue or PathValue... But unfortunately nothing is working well...

invoice-details.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.getInvoice(this.id);
    this.invoiceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'invoice_name':     [null,Validators.required],
      'invoice_amount':   [null,Validators.required],
      'invoice_category_id': [null,Validators.required],
      'invoice_price':    [null,Validators.required],
    });
}

      getInvoice(id:number){

        this.invoiceService.getInvoiceItem(id).subscribe((data:any)=> {
          console.log(this.id)
          this.id = data.id;
          this.invoiceForm.setValue({
            invoice_name : data.invoice_name,
            invoice_amount : data.invoice_amount,
            invoice_category_id: data.invoice_category_id,
            invoice_price: data.invoice_price,

          });
        });
      }
```

invoice-details.html

```
<form [formGroup]="invoiceForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input color="light" formControlName="invoice_name" inputmode="text" placeholder="name"  name="invoice_name"></ion-input>
        <ion-icon name="mail" color="orange" size="small" slot="start"></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input color="light" formControlName="invoice_amount" type="text" placeholder="amount"  name="invoice_amount"></ion-input>
        <ion-icon name="lock" color="orange" size="small" slot="start"></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item> <ion-input color="light" formControlName="invoice_category_id" inputmode="text" placeholder="category"name="invoice_category_id"></ion-input>
    <ion-icon name="contact" color="orange" size="small" slot="start"></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input color="light" formControlName="invoice_price" inputmode="text" placeholder="price" name="invoice_price"></ion-input>
    <ion-icon name="contact" color="orange" size="small" slot="start"></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
<br>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col width-50 style="text-align: center">
    <ion-button shape="round" color="orange"  type="submit" [disabled]="!invoiceForm.valid">SAVE</ion-button>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

I'm a beginner in ionic/angular

Comment: If `this.invoiceForm` is a `FormArray`. It does not accept a list of `AbstractControl`. Instead it requires the values which match the structure of the control. Can you please tell me `this.invoiceForm` type.

Comment: Hi, this.invoiceFrom is ==> invoiceForm: FormGroup

Comment: I have created demo over here please check
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-gxme2t?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: `Invoice[]` it will return array of object. Please change into `Invoice` it will work. Please check my stackblitz

Comment: I checked your stackblitz, it's what I'm expected.
I changed through my service getInvoice the Invoice[] to Invoice as you told me, but it seems it is still doesn't work.

Comment: In component level property you mention like this `name,amount,category,price` and service you have mention `Invoice`. Could you please check `subscribe((data:any)=> {...});` response data type ? whether `invoice_name,invoice_amount etc..` or `name,amount...`.

Comment: I used a console.log(data) ==> the response is [Object, Object]

Comment: @karthicvel I used your counsils to replace Invoice[] to Invoice but the issue still the same, and I checked the same issue through others post but nothing could answers my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
 getInvoice(){
      this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id']
      this.invoiceService.getInvoiceItemsByUuid(this.id).subscribe(result => {
      this.data = result
      this.form.patchValue({
        name : this.data[0]['name'],
        amount : this.data[0]['amount'],
        category_id: this.data[0]['category_id'],
        price: this.data[0]['price'],
      });
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if we had gotten a glimpse of your full code but there is one mistake that is visible:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.getInvoice(this.id);
    this.invoiceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'invoice_name':     [null,Validators.required],
      'invoice_amount':   [null,Validators.required],
      'invoice_category_id': [null,Validators.required],
      'invoice_price':    [null,Validators.required],
    });
}
```

In this function, you are calling `this.getInvoice(this.id)` before setting up the value of `this.invoiceForm`.
Maybe changing to the following could help:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.invoiceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'invoice_name':     [null,Validators.required],
      'invoice_amount':   [null,Validators.required],
      'invoice_category_id': [null,Validators.required],
      'invoice_price':    [null,Validators.required],
    });
    this.getInvoice(this.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

invoices.service.ts

```
getInvoices():Observable<Invoice[]> {
    return this.http.get<Invoice[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}api/invoices`)
}

getInvoice(id:number): Observable<Invoice[]>{
    return this.http.get<Invoice[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}api/invoices/${id}`)
}

getInvoiceItem(invoiceId:any): Observable<Invoice[]>{
    return this.http.get<Invoice[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}api/invoiceitems`)
    .pipe(
      map((invoiceitems : InvoiceItem[]) => invoiceitems.filter(inv => inv.invoice_id == invoiceId))
  );
}
```

invoice-edit.page.ts

```
invoiceForm: FormGroup;
    id:number=0;
    name ='';
    amount ='';
    category ='';
    price ='';
    created ='';
    isLoadingResults = false;
    submitted = false;

    constructor(
      private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router,
      private invoiceService: InvoicesService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    
    this.invoiceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'invoice_name':     [null,Validators.required],
      'invoice_amount':   [null,Validators.required],
      'invoice_category_id': [null,Validators.required],
      'invoice_price':    [null,Validators.required],
    });
    this.getInvoice(this.id);
}

      getInvoice(id:number){

        this.invoiceService.getInvoiceItem(id).subscribe((data:any)=> {
          console.log(this.id)
          this.id = data.id;
          this.invoiceForm.setValue({
            invoice_name : data.invoice_name,
            invoice_amount : data.invoice_amount,
            invoice_category_id: data.invoice_category_id,
            invoice_price: data.invoice_price,

          });
        });
      }

      onFormSubmit(){
        this.isLoadingResults = true;
        this.invoiceService.updateInvoice(this.id, this.invoiceForm.value)
          .subscribe((res:any) => {
            const id = res.id;
            this.isLoadingResults = false;
            this.router.navigate(['/invoice-details', id]);
          }, (err: any) => {
            console.log(err);
            this.isLoadingResults = false
          }
         );
      }

      invoiceDetails(){
        this.router.navigate(['/invoice-details', this.id])
      }
```

The invoice-edit.html is still the same

Comment: Can you remove all the name="..." attributes from the from the html of all your form fields and check?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my invoice-edit.page.ts to

```
 getInvoice(id:number){
        this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
        this.invoiceService.getInvoiceItems(this.id).subscribe(result => {
        **this.data = result**
        ***console.log(this.data)***
        this.invoiceForm.setValue({
          name : this.data.name,
          amount : this.data.amount,
          category_id: this.data.category_id,
          price: this.data.price
        });
      });
      }
```

and I retrieve my data but the setValue doesn't want to push data to variables.

[image]